# connected graph with its vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Let $ d_1 \leq d_2 \leq \cdots \leq d_n $ be the degrees of the vertices of a graph $G$, and suppose that $d_k \geq k $ for every $ k \leq n − d_n − 1 $. Show that $G$ is connected.

I have no idea how can prove this statement.

ı know If $G$ is a connected graph with degrees $d_1,\ldots,d_n$, then $D = 2|E(G)| ≥ 2(n − 1)$.ı assume that $d_1 ≥ \cdots ≥ d_n ≥ 1$. First, we claim that for every
$k = 1,\ldots,n - 1$, we have $k$
$i=1 di \ge 2k - 1$.  if $d_k \ge 2$. On the
other hand, if dk = 1, then dj = 1 for j ≥ k, and so k
i=1 di ≥ D −(n−k) ≥
2n − 2 − n + k ≥ 2k − 2.

Comment: Directed or not directed graph?

Comment: It would help if you could add even a few ideas on how you've approached the problem. It will make people more willing to help.

Comment: there is no information whether it is directed or not directed.

Answer (score 1):

#### About the assumptions

To make the statement provable at all...

- $G$ can not be a directed graph with self-loops. Consider the graph $V = \{v_1,v_2\}$ with a self-loop at $v_1$ and at $v_2$ and no other edge. It fulfills $d_1\le d_2$ (both are 2), and $d_k\ge k$, for every $k \le n - d_n - 1$. But it is not connected.
- $G$ can not be an undirected graph with self-loops. Consider the same graph as before. No matter if you count the self-loops twice or not in the degree, you still have $d_1\le d_2$ and $d_k \ge k$ for every $k \le n - d_n - 1$ (no matter whether $d_2 = 1$ or $d_1$).
- if $G$ is an arbitrary directed graph, we can not prove that $G$ is strongly connected. Consider $V = \{v_1,v_2\}$ and one edge $v_1\to v_2$. We have $d_1\le d_2$ and $d_k \ge k$ for every $k \le n - d_n - 1 = 2 - 1 -1 =0$.

So to stay provable, the statement must talk about undirected graphs without self-loops. (Or equivalentelly about directed graphs without self-loops and weak connectivity).

#### The actual proof

Name the vertices $V=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ with the degrees $d_1,\ldots,d_n$. Define
$$
L= \{ v_k \in V\mid k \le n - d_n -1\}
\text{ and }
U = \{ v_k \in V\mid k > n - d_n -1\},
$$
i.e. the "lower" and the "upper" part. Obviously, $v_n \in U$.
We proof the connectivity in two steps:

1. From every $v_k \in L$, there exists a path to some vertex from $U$
2. From every $v_k \in U$, there exists a path to $v_n$

So for part (1.), observe that for every $v_k \in L$, $d_k \ge k$. On the other hand the set $\{v_1,\ldots,v_{k-1}\}$ has only $k-1$ elements. So as $v_k$ has no self-loop, there must be some $v_\ell \in V$ with $\ell > k$ to which $v_k$ is connected by an edge. As $L$ is finite, you can repeat this until you reach $U$, i.e. for each $v_k \in L$ there is a path to some node $v_\ell \in U$.

For the part (2.), observe that $L = \{v_1,\ldots,v_{n-d_n-1}\}$, so for any $v_k\in U$, we have:
$$
   d_k \ge d_{n-d_n-1} \ge n - d_n - 1 = n - (d_n + 1)
$$
So $v_k$ is connected to at least $n - (d_n + 1)$ vertices. In other words, there are at most $d_n + 1$ vertices in $V$, $v_k$ is **not** connected to. One of them is $v_k$ itself, as the graph has no self-loops. I.e. there are at most $d_n$ vertices in $V \setminus \{v_k\}$, to which $v_k$ is not connected.

So why is there now a path from $v_k$ to $v_n$? Well for the case $v_k = v_n$ there is a trivial path of length 0. For the case of an edge $v_kv_n$, there is a path of length 1 as well. And for the case of $v_k\not= v_n$ and of no edge, there are at most $d_n -1$ vertices in $V \setminus \{v_n,v_k\}$, to which $v_k$ is not connected. So $v_k$ is connected to at least one of the $d_n$ neighbours of $v_n$, providing a path of length 2 from $v_k$ to $v_n$.

Putting (1.) and (2.) together gives that for each vertex, there is a path to $v_n$, hence the graph is connected.